# How to store input data from web page offline

Tags: php, html, caching, manifest, browser-cache

I want to store the Input data from my web page.
When I'm online, data is stored in a database, but I also want the Input data to be stored when I use the page offline.
The Input data contains of some Input Buttons, a comment box and current time stamp.
When I connect to the Internet I want to upload the data to the database.
Do you have an idea how to do it?
I thought about an chache manifest? Or Maybe store the data from the page in a text file and then upload it to db.

I hope you can help me :)

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use Javascript to save into browser's [LocalStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). Your data will be saved locally with no expiration date, even if you close browser's window.

Usage is as simple as:

```js
var user = {
    username: "john.doe",
    email: "john.doe@mail.com"
}

window.localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
```

One way to implement it could be (Using JQuery). I can't test if this code works right now, but I believe you can get the idea:

I am using Javascript's [navigator.online](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine/onLine) to check connectivity.

**profile.html**

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="save_profile.php">
            Name:<br>
            <input type="text" name="name">
            <br>
            Email:<br>
            <input type="text" name="email">
            <br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" onclick="validate()">
        </form> 
    </body>
</html>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        //This synch can be executed on every page
        var needsSynch = window.localStorage.getItem('needs_synch');
        if (needsSynch) {
            synchronizeOfflineData();
        }

        function synchronizeOfflineData()
        {
            var userData = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('user_data'));

            $.ajax({
                url : "save_profile.php",
                type : 'post',
                data : {
                     nome : userData.name,
                     email : userData.email
                }, 
                success: function(result){
                    window.localStorage.setItem('needs_synch', false);
                    window.localStorage.removeItem('user_data');
                } 
            });
        }

        function validate()
        {
            //submit form if you are offline
            if (window.navigator.online) {
                return true;
            }

            saveToLocalStorage();
            window.top.location= = "http://yourdomain.com/offline_success_page.html";
        }

        function saveToLocalStorage()
        {
            var userData = {
                name: $('input[name=name]').value,    
                email: $('input[name=email]').value    
            };
            //a flag to indicate that there is data waiting to synchronize when online
            window.localStorage.setItem('needs_synch', true);
            window.localStorage.setItem('user_data', JSON.stringify(userData));
        }  
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Should I just copy this to my php file? How can I then send the data to the database after i go online?

Comment: @Astra-Joe I edited the answer with a full example. Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks a lot for the code! I will try it and give u the answer